# Getting Azure Web App instance id's

Tags: asp.net, azure

I'm trying to get the instance id's for an Azure Web App. I know the app are running on 2 active instances, but when I use the [GetInstanceIds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.websiteoperationsextensions.getinstanceids%28v=azure.11%29.aspx) of the [WebSiteManagementClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.management.websites.websitemanagementclient%28v=azure.11%29.aspx) API I only get 1 ID:

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2();
cert.Import(Convert.FromBase64String("cert_string"));

var client = new WebSiteManagementClient(new CertificateCloudCredentials("id_to_sub", cert));
var instanceIds = client.WebSites.GetInstanceIds("webspace_name", "webapp_name");
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar behavior.  In my testing, it seems like there were a few factors:

- This API returns nothing for "free" instances
- In some cases it takes a few minutes of use for every instance to spin up
- In some cases, the "WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID" environment variable would return a value not listed in the results from this API.

I think the second item is the most likely issue based on what you described.  Try turning on "Always On" and hitting the site a few times, then checking the result.